# What is the relation of Lp bound between tightness?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $\{f_n\}$  is bounded in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and $f_n$ is a sequence of function.
Assume that $p$ is larger than 1  but $p$ is not infinite.
Is this sequence tight?

Comment: How are you defining tightness?  I edited your post slightly to improve the formatting.  Have I changed the meaning at all?

Comment: No. The answer is correct!

Answer (score 1):

No, $L^p$ boundedness does not get you tightness. Consider $f_n=\chi_{[n,n+1]}$, as in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/128055).

To get tightness, you'd need a weight that grows at infinity. That is, let $w$  be  a nonnegative locally integrable function such that $w(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to \pm \infty$. If the integrals 
$\int_{\mathbb R} |f_n| w$ are uniformly bounded, then the sequence $(f_n)$ is tight. The proof is straightforward using $$\int_{|x|\ge M} |f_n| \le \frac{1}{\min_{|x|\ge M} w(x)}\int \int_{\mathbb R} |f_n| w$$